# Compare textbox.text to a database column to find matching usernames

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I'm trying to do a registration system that should compare if username exists in database.

This is my table

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Registros] (
[ID_Utilizador]          INT          IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
[NomeUtilizador]         VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
[PasseUtilizador]        VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
[EmailUtilizador]        VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[NomeCompletoUtilizador] VARCHAR (50) NOT NULL,
[PaisUtilizador]         CHAR (10)    NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ID_Utilizador] ASC)
);
```

This should verify if user exists in the column "NomeUtilizador" some reason ..but it doesn't work for

```
    if (IsPostBack)
    {
        SqlConnection conexao = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrosConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        conexao.Open();

        string cmdstr = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Registros WHERE NomeUtilizador ='"+TBusername.Text+"'";

        SqlCommand UserExists= new SqlCommand(cmdstr, conexao);

        int temp = Convert.ToInt32(UserExists.ExecuteScalar().ToString());

        conexao.Close();

        if (temp ==1)
        {
            Response.Write(" UsernameAlreadyExists! <br /> choose another ");
        }
    }
}
```

Solution

```
   protected void BTsubmeter_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlDataReader reader = null;
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["RegistrosConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Table where NomeUtilizador=@NomeUtilizador", conn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NomeUtilizador", TBusername.Text);
    reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    if (reader != null && reader.HasRows)
    {
        //if username is matching 
        Response.Write(" Username Exists! <br />Choose another ");
        conn.Close();
    }
    else
    {
        //if not matching do something
    }
```

P.S : Thanks to everybody that tried to help and have a nice day :)

Comment: "doesn't work" is really abstract problem definition.

Comment: You can do by setting `NomeUtilizador` as `primary key`.Its also a possibility